# How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple value in one row of a columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the values from column without duplication no problem to do so

that what I did

```
<?php
   $getSize = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT pSize FROM products');
          while ($gs = mysqli_fetch_array($getSize)) {
      ?>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><label for="size">
              <input type="checkbox" name="size" id="size"
              value="<?php print $gs['pSize'] ?>"> <?php print $gs['pSize'] ?></label>
         </a>
       </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

the problem is in some rows I have multiple values like this

```
30|
30
30|35|40
30|20|35
```

and here 30 is value and 35 is another one and 40 is third one

so what I need is `30|35|40` will be as

```
30
35
40
```

and this will be for each row.

Comment: That database sounds like a huge mess

Answer (score 0):

in your case `pSize = emp_firstname` and  `products =employee_master`
check following example

```
SELECT
  emp_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(emp_firstname, ',', n.digit+1), '|', -1) emp_firstname
FROM
  employee_master
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(emp_firstname, '|' , '')) <= LENGTH(emp_firstname)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  emp_id,
  n.digit
```